# How to use h264 stream as an input for OpenTok publisher?

Tags: ios, opentok, tokbox

I'm using an OpenTok iOS sdk. I have a h264 video stream (annexB or avc, doesn't really matter) and I want to use it as an input for OpenTok publisher. What's the best way to accomplish that? Do I need to decode the video or can pass it directly?

Answer (score 0):

You must decode it first, and then, pass the raw frame to the OpenTok publisher.